# How to pass in undefined parameters when use subparsers

Tags: python, argparse, subparsers

When I use the subparsers, the subparers are optional parameters, and I have to choose one of them. Now, I want to implement the ability to pass in a default option when an option parameter that is not defined in the subparse is passed in, for example, the`add_codition`.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser.add_argument('add_condition', nargs='*')

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help', dest="character")
subparsers.required = False

# create the parser for the "a" command
parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('a', help='a help')
parser_a.add_argument('--bar', choices='ABC', help='bar help')

# create the parser for the "b" command
parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('b', help='b help')
parser_b.add_argument('--baz', choices='XYZ', help='baz help')
```

However, when I pass in options that a subparser and b parser don't have, e.g. `key=value`. The `key=value`should theoretically be passed in `add_codition`.

The program result always prompts: `error: argument character: invalid choice: 'key' (choose from 'a', 'b')`

The python version is 3.6.9.

Comment: Because the first positional is a '*', any input string will get assigned to the next positional, the subparsers, hence the complaint that 'key' is not a valid subparser name.  Using any variable nargs argument in the main (positional or optional) is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding 'add-condition' as a positional argument.  If you are trying to do a key=value type argument then you need to use an optional argument.  Positional arguments don't take a key.

Some examples of positional arguments would be the path given to the `cd` command or `ls` command

```
cd ~/Documents
#  ~/Documents is the positional argument
ls .
# . is the positional argument
```

Optional arguments are the ones that can be structured as key value pairs, or they can be used as boolean flags. For example in cli for the `curl` program using the `--config` followed by a filename points curl to use that specific filename as the config file. That is an example of the key value pair.  Also in curl you can use the `--get` which can be interpreted as `get=True` and tells the program to send get requests instead of the default post requests.

So if you are trying to use `key=value` it should look more like this. You can still specify nargs="*" then the parser will consider everything following the `key=` to be a single list argument with multiple space seperated items in it, or until it finds another valid argument.

```
parser.add_argument("--key", action='store', help="requires a value")
```